# How much do conditionals affect performance?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, performance

How much do conditionals effect performance? For example, would code A execute faster than code B since it is only checking the boolean value once? (`data` is a `DataTable` in this example)

Code A:

```
bool isBusiness = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data["businessName") ? false : true;
if(isBusiness) {
    var name = data["businessName"];
    var id = data["businessId"];
    var phone = data["businessPhone"];
    var address = data["businessAddress"];
}
else {
    var name = data["customerName"];
    var id = data["customerId"];
    var phone = data["customerPhone"];
    var address = data["customerAddress"];
}
```

Code B:

```
bool isBusiness = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data["businessName") ? false : true;
var name = isBusiness ? data["businessName"] : data["customerName"];
var id = isBusiness ? data["businessId"] : data["customerId"];
var phone = isBusiness ? data["businessPhone"] : data["customerPhone"];
var address = isBusiness ? data["businessAddress"] : data["customerAddress"];
```

This is a small example so the actual difference would be small, but what if I were mapping hundreds of rows like this? Some care about the `isBusiness` flag and some don't. Does anyone have any statistical evidence one way or the other?

Comment: it is taking one cpu cycle to check, so hundreds of rows is nothing

Comment: Why asking? Measure it. Besides that i would expect the Indexer access via string the slowest thing in your code. If you want to optimize your code look at how your data class does that.

Comment: If you have performance problems here, it's surely not caused by the `if` statements. It's probably caused by the HORRIBLE, magic-string-based, untyped DataTable stuff where everything is `object` and needs to be casted / boxed/unboxed at runtime. Create a proper data model or use an ORM instead.

Comment: If you want to find out how fast your horse runs, do you ask strangers on the internet or do you time your horse?

Comment: @HighCore I am not having any performance issues, this was merely a thought. Unfortunately, I need to use the "HORRIBLE, magic-string-based, untyped DataTable stuff" because I am mapping over 1000 fields spread over 10 mapping classes. And due to the requirements, I need to use a DataTable.

Comment: @gwin003 if you don't have performance issues why are you even worrying about that? I'd rather care about removing the horrible code and doing something more maintainable.

Comment: @HighCore I'm not worrying about it, just asking because I was curious.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clear answer for this question. It depends on how many rows etc, the only one who can answer it is you. To test it you can simply use the [Stopwatch](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) class.

I don't think there will be many/any difference, so I would say A, since it is more readable/editable.

Answer (score 0):

## *I agree with other responders here*; however, I would like to add to this.

The performance hit incurred by if statements is something to be taken into consideration if a given method will be run often. If you would like to learn more about the specifics of this effecting performance, I recommend reading this post about [conditional branching.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/580683)

That being said, I will say that you get a pretty much **Insignificant Performance Boost** by changing the first line of code from this:

```
bool isBusiness = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data["businessName") ? false : true;
```

to this:

```
bool isBusiness = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data["businessName");
```

### Though, out of the two options I prefer the first one

The reason for this, is that if you would like to push for some code clarity, you could refactor it from this:

```
bool isBusiness = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data["businessName") ? false : true;
if(isBusiness) {
   var name = data["businessName"];
   var id = data["businessId"];
   var phone = data["businessPhone"];
   var address = data["businessAddress"];
}
else {
   var name = data["customerName"];
   var id = data["customerId"];
   var phone = data["customerPhone"];
   var address = data["customerAddress"]; 
}
```

to this:

```
bool isBusiness = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data["businessName");
if(isBusiness) {
   this.MapBusinessRow(data);
}
else {
   this.MapCustomerRow(data)
}
```

*Though, I must say, that is purely for readability and is not for performance.*

**At the end of the day, if you are worried about it; Test It!**